# Structure tags and text inside button

Tags: html

I would like to know how should I structure html in the example above:

1-)

```html
 <h1>My Title</h1>
    <a href="#">My
     <span class="hide">Button</span>
    </a>
```

2-)

```html
 <h1>My Title</h1>
    <a href="#">
      <span>My<span>
      <span class="hide">Button</span>
    </a>
```

I have this doubt, if I should put the My inside a span tag too.

Answer (score 1):

Without span tag it will work.

```
<h1>My Title</h1>
<a href="#">My
 <span class="hide">Button</span>
</a>
```

If you want you can place span tag. But no need for that.
You forgot to close `<span>` tag in your 2nd html code for `my`.

```
<h1>My Title</h1>
<a href="#">
  <span>My</span>
  <span class="hide">Button</span>
</a>
```

Comment: So i should use the My inside span tag? Why??

Comment: If you want to give span then you can give for design purpose. otherwise no need.

Answer (score 0):

div is a block level,means on its own separate line.where as  is of type inline.and  is an tag to define hyperlink

where div is used to wrap large part of information and span is used  for smaller part of information/Text and "a" for hyper link.
For more information refer following [Html Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/Overview.html)

And in your code :-

```
     <h1>My Title</h1>
<a href="#">
  <span>My</span>
  <span class="hide">Button</span>
</a>
```

make this change .

Comment: Yes but it can be only applied to small group of document.